# How to mimic enter programmatically in DevTools console

Tags: javascript, dom

I am stuck.  I am writing a test for our chatbot.  I enter a sentence or phrase then confirm its response.  I am currently walking through the steps in chrome DevTools.

The steps I have so fare:

*** Click to make the chatbot active

```
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-message-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('#messageList').click()
```

*** Typing something into the input field

```
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-user-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('div').lastElementChild.firstElementChild.value = "TESTING THIS"
```

After this step I need a way to mimic the action of pressing enter on a keyboard.

I have found some articles but non of them really helped.

I have tried this:

```
const enterKey = 13
const event = new KeyboardEvent('enterKey',{'key':enterKey});
document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

It will return true but nothing happens.

I've also tried the following:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$(".input-box-wrapper").trigger(e);
```

This does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if helpful, but i'd suggest you have a look at puppeteer instead of reinventing the wheel; https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Comment: Try dispatching the event on the input field?!?

Comment: I would avoid 3rd party/libraries, including jquery...

Comment: if your writing e2e test, I recommend using cypress

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am working on a proof of concept with another automation tool called Cyara.  Because of the shadow-root elements in the chatbot I have to pragmatically do it this way.